# Why can't I read fstream's binary data with operator>>?

Tags: c++, binary, stream, fstream

If I do something like the following:

```
ifstream file;
file.open("somefile", ios::binary);

unsigned int data;

file >> data;
```

My stream will always set the `failbit` and the `data` will remain uninitialized.  However, if I read a `char` or `unsigned char` instead, the stream is fine.  `perror()` is telling me "result too large".

The only thing I saw on Google was a suggestion saying that `operator>>` shouldn't be used for binary data (prefer `read()`), but I find the operator to be cleaner and easier to use -- and it doesn't require casting everything.

Can someone explain this issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [iostream extraction operator (>>)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) attempts to interpret numerical strings separated by whitespace, not binary data. There are many different ways to encode an unsigned integer in binary form (e.g. a 32-bit [2's complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) in [little-endian byte order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)). That's why you must use the [read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/read/)/[write](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/write/) functions to operate on such binary buffers.

However, nothing prevents you from implementing your own class for serializing binary data in whatever form you wish using the insertion and extraction operators. Such a class would likely use the read function of an ifstream object internally. Alternatively, the [boost serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) may already hold exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It should be done as described by you. However, the C++ standard designers are not very elegant. In fact, there are a lot of flaws in the design of C++, even C++11 and C++14 has lots of defects.

**The ideal C++ design should be that:**

1.For text file:

```
ifstream fin_txt("input.txt");
int i;
float j;
double k;
fin_txt >> i >> j >> k;
```

This will read in 3 strings and parse into integer, float and double, and store them into i, j, and k respectively.

2.For binary file:

```
ifstream fin_txt("input.bin", ios::binary);
int i;
float j;
double k;
fin_txt >> i >> j >> k;
```

This will read in 4/8 bytes (depending on whether int is 32-bit or 64-bit), 4 bytes and 8 bytes binary data and store them into i, j, and k respectively.

Unfortunately, **the current design** is to report an error for Case 2. Maybe this can be achieved in C++22.

Comment: You've got the reason why it's this way in your answer: "depending on whether int is 32-bit or 64-bit". Currently, code using `<iostreams>` is portable, your proposal is not.

Comment: To @Caleth, well, as I said, that is another design defect in the standard C++, it should distinguish between int32 and int64 instead of just int, which can be 32-bit or 64-bit, maybe 128-bit in the future. The field-size deterministicity of int is different from others (char=8-bits, long=32-bits, long long=64-bits, float=32-bits, double=64-bits).
To resolve, we can simply define int32 and int64 respectively, and a runtime error is thrown if a field-size non-deterministic type is given for a binary file, i.e.
fin_txt >> i; // throws an error, 
fin_txt >> (int32)i; // compile correctly

Comment: That's not what `ios::binary` (and `ios::text`) are for. Some platforms distinguish between "text mode" and "binary mode" in how they present files with line ending characters. The `ios` flags *only* deal with that.

Comment: @Caleth then there could be a text stream with operators>> and << done using text formatting and a binary stream, another class, with >> done as binary write