# Wide char input stream std::wifstream is getting corrupt while deserializing object which was serialized using std::wofstream

Tags: c++, serialization, iostream, corrupt

I am trying to write my own custom serialize and de-serialize for an object of my application. I know there are plenty of libraries like boost serialize etc. available for ready use but I wanted to learn this serialize and de-serialize hence this effort.

Problem occurs when I try to de-serialize(using std::wifstream) the object I had serialized(using std::wofstream). Not able to read even one class member correctly. First 3 members I am trying to de-serialize are bool, but they read incorrect values from the file stream. Can someone please suggest any pointers as to what could be the problem here. Thanks for your time.

Typedefs in application:

```
namespace fc
{
#ifdef UNICODE
    typedef std::wstring tstring;
    typedef std::wfstream tfstream;
    typedef std::wofstream tofstream;
    typedef std::wifstream tifstream;
    typedef std::wstringstream tstringstream;
#else
    typedef std::string tstring;
    typedef std::fstream tfstream;
    typedef std::ofstream tofstream;
    typedef std::ifstream tifstream;
    typedef std::stringstream tstringstream;
#endif

    typedef std::vector<fc::tstring> tstrvec;
    typedef std::vector<fc::tstring> tstrvec;
}
```

Object being serialized and de-serialize:

```
struct FastCopyCfg
{
    bool mOverwriteFiles;
    bool mCopySystemFiles;
    bool mCopyHiddenFiles;
    fc::tstring mDstFolder;
    fc::tstrvec mSrcFiles;
    fc::tstrvec mSrcFolders;
    fc::tstrvec mIncludeWildcards;
    fc::tstrvec mExcludeWildcards;

    FastCopyCfg()
    {
        mOverwriteFiles = false;
        mCopySystemFiles = false;
        mCopyHiddenFiles = false;
        mDstFolder.clear();
        mSrcFiles.clear();
        mSrcFolders.clear();
        mIncludeWildcards.clear();
        mExcludeWildcards.clear();
    }

    template<typename Archive>
    void Serialize(Archive& ar, const std::uint16_t = 0)
    {
        ar & mCopySystemFiles & mCopyHiddenFiles & mOverwriteFiles &
            mDstFolder & mSrcFiles & mSrcFolders & mIncludeWildcards & mExcludeWildcards;
    }
};
```

Global insertion and extraction operators overloaded:

```
void operator >>(IArchive& ar, FastCopyCfg& cfg)
{
    cfg.Serialize(ar);
}

void operator <<(OArchive& ar, FastCopyCfg& cfg)
{
    cfg.Serialize(ar);
}
```

Archiver classes

```
class OArchive
{
    std::wostream& mStream;

public:
    OArchive(std::wostream& stream) :mStream(stream){}

    template<typename Val>
    OArchive& operator &(std::vector<Val>& vtr)
    {
        mStream << vtr.size();
        std::for_each(vtr.begin(), vtr.end(), [&](auto e) {mStream << e; });
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename DT>
    OArchive& operator &(DT& data)
    {
        mStream << data;
        return *this;
    }
};

class IArchive
{
    std::wistream& mStream;

public:
    IArchive(std::wistream& stream) :mStream(stream) {}

    template<typename Val>
    IArchive& operator &(std::vector<Val>& vtr)
    {
        std::vector<Val>::value_type vElement;
        std::vector<Val>::size_type vSize = 0;

        mStream >> vSize;
        for (std::vector<Val>::size_type i = 0; i < vSize; i++)
        {
            mStream >> vElement;
            vtr.push_back(vElement);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename DT>
    IArchive& operator &(DT& data)
    {
        try
        {
            mStream >> data;
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            Logger::logDebug("Exception while reading config file: ", e.what());
        }
        catch (...)
        {
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Serialization using code. I set the flag to true and false to debug serialization and de-serialization.

```
bool flag = false;
void CFastCopyDlg::OnBnClickedButtonSaveConfiguration()
{
    if (flag)
    {
        fc::tofstream file(fc::CONFIG_FILENAME, fc::tofstream::binary);
        OArchive ar(file);
        ar << getCopyConfig();
    }
    else
    {
        fc::tifstream file(fc::CONFIG_FILENAME, fc::tifstream::binary);
        IArchive ar(file);
        FastCopyCfg cfg;
        ar >> cfg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  If the issue is deserialization, that has nothing to do with button clicks.  A simple class with maybe one bool and one `std::wstring` with hard-coded values, with a 3 or 4 line `main` function that simply serializes and deserializes the simple struct.  Then use the debugger to debug that simple code to isolate the issue (and maybe even discover what the issue is).  Right now, you're cluttering things with aspects of the program that are not important in solving the issue.

Comment: Also, it isn't wise to write all of this code and not know what the final outcome will be using this serialization library.  You should have started with something simple (as stated in my first comment), just to test things out.

Comment: You write all strings in the vector, one after another with no delimiters. How do you hope to separate them again when reading back? For that matter, suppose you have a vector with one string `"23a"`. The serialization code would produce a piece of text `123a` (the size `1` immediately followed by the string). When parsing back, you will read `123` into the size, and then attempt to read 123 strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem. The issue is, de-serialization using any std fstream  when file is opened in binary mode CAN NOT be done using the extraction operator >>. Similar topic was discussed [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151840/why-cant-i-read-fstreams-binary-data-with-operator). Please refer below code to see where the problem existed in the question code.

```
class IArchive
{
    std::wistream& mStream;

public:
    IArchive(std::wistream& stream) :mStream(stream) {}

    template<typename Val>
    IArchive& operator &(std::vector<Val>& vtr)
    {
        std::vector<Val>::value_type vElement;
        std::vector<Val>::size_type vSize = 0;

        mStream >> vSize;
        for (std::vector<Val>::size_type i = 0; i < vSize; i++)
        {
            mStream >> vElement;
            vtr.push_back(vElement);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename DT>
    IArchive& operator &(DT& data)
    {
        try
        {
            mStream >> data; // PROBLEM - BINARY DATA CANNOT BE READ USING >>
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            Logger::logDebug("Exception while reading config file: ", e.what());
        }
        catch (...)
        {
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```